# civiCRM installation on Wordpress - blank screen

Tags: wordpress

I tried installing civiCRM on Wordpress 4.1, and the admin page came up blank when I clicked on the CiviCRM link from the menu bar on the left.

The error message I am getting (by clicking F12 in the browser, on the console screen) is:

> Uncaught TypeError: CRM.url is not a function(anonymous function) @ admin.php?page=CiviCRM:44
>
> admin.php?page=CiviCRM:61 GET https://checkout.google.com/seller/gsc/v2/cart.js?mid=987654321012345
>
> load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-datepicker,jquery…:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

This is the code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var CRM = {"config":{"userFramework":"WordPress","resourceBase":"\/wp-content\/plugins\/civicrm\/civicrm\/","lcMessages":"en_US"}};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
CRM.url('init', '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/example&placeholder');
CRM.formatMoney('init', "$ 1234.56");
</script>
```

Can someone help me please?

```
CiviCRM version: 4.4
CMS version: Wordpress 4.1
MySQL version: 5.6.24
PHP version: 5.3.26
```

Comment: Are you sure it uploaded completely? These errors are similar to those you'd get with missing files.

Comment: Yes it did say that the installation was successful. Which files could be missing?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to run the installer again. Unless you've modified component files, it won't cause problems.

Comment: Tried re-installing. No change. Then, I disabled the plugins one by one. Now the error showing up on the screen related to the smarty  template engine. The error in the console of the browser is still the same, CRM.url is not a function.

Comment: Warning: Smarty error: problem creating directory 'E:/HostingSpaces/cma2011' in E:\HostingSpaces\cma2011\mydomain.org\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1094

Warning: include(E:\HostingSpaces\cma2011\mydomain.org\wwwroot/wp-content/plugins\files\civicrm\templates_c\en_US\\%%E6\E65\E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\HostingSpaces\cma2011\mydomain.org\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1264

Comment: Please add new information and code to your question, not in comments. Looks like maybe a file permissions problem.